# Replica is not created containers in Docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

step 1: I have created a Docker file and build one custom image in all 4 nodes of my docker swarm cluster.

step 2: While I am trying to create a service in my manager node with the below command, the process is kept on continuing without stop. If I forcefully stop it by ctrl+c, I can see service is created with docker service ls command. But the replica is not created, means in Replica section it is showing 0/1.

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER nityaranjan190592@gmail.com

RUN yum install -y httpd \
        zip \ 
        unzip 

ADD https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/download/page247/kindle.zip /var/www/html/ 

WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN unzip kindle.zip
RUN cp -rvf markups-kindle/* .
RUN rm -rf __MACOSX markups-kindle kindle.zip

CMD ["/user/sbin/httpd" , "-D" , "FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

```sh
docker image build -t webimage:1 . 
docker service create --name webserver -p 80:80 webimage:1
```

Comment: Dockerfile which I used to create image:
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER nityaranjan190592@gmail.com
RUN yum install -y httpd \
         zip \
         unzip
ADD https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/download/page247/kindle.zip /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN unzip kindle.zip
RUN cp -rvf markups-kindle/* .
RUN rm -rf __MACOSX markups-kindle kindle.zip
CMD ["/user/sbin/httpd" , "-D" , "FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
docker image build -t webimage:1 .
docker service create --name webserver -p 80:80 webimage:1

Comment: I think you want to start the container. Check how the `docker run` works: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/